Java Point<G2D> over the network
I am maintaining a software that we need to pass an object of this type:
org.geolatte.geom.Point<org.geolatte.geom.G2D>,
I have customized deserialiser as such:
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import org.geolatte.geom.G2D;
import org.geolatte.geom.Point;
import org.geolatte.geom.builder.DSL;
import org.geolatte.geom.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem;
import static org.geolatte.geom.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystems.WGS84;
import static org.geolatte.geom.builder.DSL.g;
import static org.geolatte.geom.builder.DSL.point;

import java.io.IOException;

// public class PointG2DDeserializer {
public class PointG2DDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Point<G2D>> {
   @Override
    public Point<G2D> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("XXXXXX 1 PointG2DDeserializer.deserialize invoked,WGS84="+WGS84 +",p="+p.toString());

        try {
            JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
            JsonNode coordinates = node.get("coordinates");

            if (coordinates == null) {
                System.out.println("XXXXXX 2 coordinates node is null");
                return point(WGS84, new G2D(0.1, 0.2));
            } else {
                double x = coordinates.get(0).asDouble();
                double y = coordinates.get(1).asDouble();
                System.out.println("XXXXXX 3 coordinates node is not null");
                return point(WGS84, new G2D(x, y));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XXXXXX 4 Error during deserialization: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}

I know my request message definitely has "coordinates" JSON element, but above function always output:
XXXXXX 2 coordinates node is null

Anybody has any idea?

Well, if you have:
@JsonDeserialize(using = PointG2DDeserializer.class)
public class Point<T> {

    private T coordinates;

    // constructors, getters, setters

}

Check it with some tests:
public class PointG2DDeserializerTest {

    private static final double DELTA = 0.1D;

    @Test
    public void havingCoordinates() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper givenMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String givenJson = "{ \"coordinates\": [5.0, 10.9] }";

        Point<G2D> resultPoint = givenMapper.readValue(givenJson, Point.class);

        assertEquals(resultPoint.getCoordinates().getX(), 5.0, DELTA);
        assertEquals(resultPoint.getCoordinates().getY(), 10.9, DELTA);
    }

    @Test
    public void whenCoordinatesAreAbsentThenDefaults() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper givenMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String givenJson = "{ \"someOtherField\": \"someOtherValue\" }";

        Point<G2D> resultPoint = givenMapper.readValue(givenJson, Point.class);

        assertEquals(resultPoint.getCoordinates().getX(), 0.1, DELTA);
        assertEquals(resultPoint.getCoordinates().getY(), 0.2, DELTA);
    }

}

So, try to debug/log the request body

I could convert it to JSON string and read back into an object. My problem is that when the object is transferred over network, it always complained no "coordinates" attribute. The customized deserializer is called before it reached the controller method. In other words, it never reached the controller
